# Percolation and diameter of graph

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, percolation

Is the critical probability in percolation and diameter of graph related. I guess larger the diameter higher the probability. Is there any result like this?
By critical probability I mean the probability at the which the largest component is of size $\theta(n)$.

Comment: What do you mean by "critical probability" if the graph is finite?

Comment: What if you compare a complete graph and a cycle graph with the same number of vertices?